# recovering coins from a faulty laptop to my desktop

Tags: wallet

My laptop screen died and although I was able to recover all the data when I reinstalled qt on my desktop and it finally synced after some crashes there was no transaction history and 0 balance. I upgraded to 8.5 Qt but still nothing.I have backups of wallet.dat but I did encrypt it on my laptop. have read a ton of posts but nothing seems to cover how i get bitcon qt to open or read the dat file. Its been six months since my last transaction, do i need to recover other data from my laptop and how do i know if my encrypted wallet still has info on it? help a midlife crisis!